# HMS Map Kit - React Native Marker Problem

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

What could be the reason why the map works in my React Native application but my markers don't work? Are React native and native methods different?

Answer (score 1):

[React Native Sample Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zk4Z6.png)

Maybe you forgot to set the marker for mapview.

Also If you want check HMS Map Kit sample codes for React Native:

https://github.com/hms-dtse-dxb/react-native-hms-map#rendering-a-list-of-markers-on-a-map

Answer (score 0):

Our team is working on this fix and a new version of the sdk will be released coming week.

Thanks!